# Prevent BuildCraft Item Drops

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit, minecraft-buildcraft

I currently own a server with about 40 players at peak times, and there are these few players who build MASSIVE factories out of BuildCraft pipes. I have looked through all of the config files of Buildcraft and even tried de-compiling it's source code. Is there any way to prevent this without banning the pipes? I am using Tekkit Classic.

Comment: What do you want exactly? Users to be able to build "some pipes" but not "Too many"?

Comment: I want bc drops to be deleted lets say 3 seconds after they drop out of a pipe. You can do this with the BC config in the new Tekkit, but it's different in Classic.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to combat this

1. upgrade to logistics pipes they are a lot smarter although a little more expensive.
2. Request that users put obsidian void pipe overflows where the item drops may occur, best way to implement this is to supply them to the users.
3. Use OP commands to delete entities on a schedule say once an hour. (can be problimatic when people drop items at the wrong time so set a warning message up)
        Can also be implemented with bukkit plugins.
4. ask people to use pipe converters to change pipe type at end points of the system. thus being cheaper than changing their entire pipe system.

To my knowledge these are the best options for working this issue out.

I hope this helps. if anyone would like to add to this list feel free.

Comment: I would do that, but most players won't comply with it. I already have a plugin to remove entities, but if I set it to a smaller time frame, players complain, and if I set it to a larger one, it laggs

Comment: And there are no logistic pipes in tekkit classic to my knowledge

Comment: Apologise for the logistics pipes. haven't used tekkit lite in a while. I would say your best option is to give them void pipe overflows. or if there are enderchests give them each one with outputs at a central location to a void pipe. only way without disrupting the other users and wont create extra lag

Comment: there is no void pipe

Comment: Are there obsidian pipes, sorry its been a long time since i used the older versions of buildcraft, i tend to use the updated ones. You can make ghetto voids using obsidian pipes into lava. basically you need to enforce players to have an overflow system. you just tell them if they don't find a way then you will have to ban the pipes for the good of the server.

Comment: There are obsidian pipes, that looks like the best solution to me